# Is there a simple way to do math with two operators and three numbers?

Tags: python, math

I'm making a math game and i want a question with three numbers and two operators e.g `a + b + c`. The method i'm using now is:

```
import operator
ops = { "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub} # etc.
print(ops["+"](10,5))
```

Does anyone know a simple way to have two operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `ops` dictionary that is used to map each of the operator to its corresponding mathematical operation, further you can define the `ops_pr` (operation priorities) dictionary that represents the priority of each operation in the context of mathematical operations. And then based on the information from these two dictionaries we can determine the result of the given expression.

Use:

```
import operator

def calc_exp(a, b, c, op1, op2):
    ops = {"/": lambda x, y: x / y, "*": operator.mul, "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub}
    ops_pr = {"/": 4, "*": 3, "+": 2, "-": 1}

    if ops_pr[op1] >= ops_pr[op2]:
        return ops[op2](ops[op1](a, b), c)
    return ops[op1](a, ops[op2](b, c))
```

Calling the function:

```
print(calc_exp(10, 20, 30, '+', '+')) # 10 + 20 + 30
print(calc_exp(10, 20, 30, '-', '-')) # 10 - 20 - 30
print(calc_exp(10, 20, 30, '+', '*')) # 10 + 20 * 30
print(calc_exp(10, 20, 30, '*', '/')) # 10 * 20 / 30
```

This prints:

```
60
-40
610
6.666666666666666
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
ops = { "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub} # etc.
a = 10
b = 5
x = lambda a, b:print(ops["+"](a,b),ops["-"](a,b))
x(a,b)
# 15 5
```